# How to delete api endpoint in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I created an example endpoint in my app and deployed the module on app engine. After I delete that endpoint(by deleting the file) I get the following error when trying to run the backend module

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':be:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'. > There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: com.my.package.MyEndpoint

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found one solution. The issue is with the `web.xml` file that the task `appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs` is looking up to generate endpoints. It does not seem to update when an endpoint is deleted. I had to manually delete the reference to the deleted endpoint.

Path to `web.xml` -> `<path-to-backend-module>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`